# Single sign on with Worklight apps

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst

All,

Would like to know if we can single sign-on with Worklight apps in the device. For example, an enterprise plans to launch a bunch of Worklight apps in their local app store and would like to have SSO for all the worklight apps in the same device. Meaning that if the user opens and logins into one of the Worklight apps in the device successfullym he/she should not be asked for authentication in other Worklight apps in the same device.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Search for "SSO" in the [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp).

Comment: IBM Worklight infocenter has high level info about SSO which is good enough to start with. Just wondering if anybody is successful with creating custom authentication to support SSO. If so, please share your experience.